# Why there are so many <style> tags in template when using Vue?

Tags: html, vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js

I am new to Vue and I tried to google this question but didn't find anything. Is it ok to have so many styles in HTML? or do I have to fix it somehow?[Here is the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ9DX.png)

Comment: If you're referring to the automatically injected style tags during development, they will not be present in a production build of your application.

Comment: @skirtle, oh, so they will be gone, ok thanks a lot

Comment: mine are still there in production. TBH even in dev it makes inspecting styles / css a nightmare and surely slows it down too.